# How to use TestDisk to recover a formatted Time Machine drive

Tags: data-recovery

I bought a new portable drive to use as my Time Machine drive, but stupidly forgot to backup some files from the old Time Machine drive before I formatted it, and now I need to recover some files. I searched through this website and found that TestDisk has been repeatedly suggested for this situation. I have downloaded it but found it rather cryptic to use. Its website does not have much help either. Can anyone walk me through how to use Test Disk please? Thank you

EDIT: More details
My original partition was this:
Partition 1: Time Machine, 600GB
Partition 2: Regular backup drive, 400GB

Current Partition:
Partition 1: Time Machine 1, 500 GB
Partition 2: Time Machine 2, 500 GB
Two Time Machines for two devices.

Comment: The drive you formatted was being used for Time Machine, right? So it had to have been formatted HFS+ and assuming it's still HFS+ then according to [13 Recover deleted files](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step#Recover_deleted_files) under [TestDisk Step By Step](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step#Recover_deleted_files), TestDisk does not recover files on an HFS+ Filesystem.  Try [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your coment. On the very front page of the wiki at the bottom it says TestDisk can recover LOST PARTITIONS including HFS+. Is that a different concept than recovering deleted files? Thanks

Comment: Yes, they are different processes.  If all you did was reformat, i.e. erased the existing partition without changing its physical size then I do not believe TeskDisk will be of much help.  If you could update your question with more technical details as to what exactly you did then that might help others to provide more detailed help.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the original question with more details. I hope it helps.

Comment: Can anyone help please?